# how to store rss in mysql with Magpie in php

Tags: php, mysql, magpie

I need to fetch rss feeds from 12 different websites.
and i want only selected feeds will be display to user on main page. I am using Magpie RSS parser to display RSS feeds. But how i can store them in database. I used following code to fetch feeds.

```
<?php
include('magpierss/rss_fetch.inc');
define('MAGPIE_CACHE_DIR', '/var/cache');
$rss = fetch_rss(' here is url link');
$items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, 10);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $href = $item['link'];
    $title = $item['title'];
    $desc = $item['description'];
    echo "<p><a href='$href'>$title</a><br>";
    if ($desc) {
        if (strlen($desc) >= 125) {
            $desc = substr($desc, 0, 124) . "...";
        }
    }
    echo $desc;
}
;
?>
```

now how i can store it to database.

Comment: Can't understand what part of storing is problematic for you. Can you write what you have tried? What tables do you have in DB?

Comment: You can create simple query, but the main question is: "Is it a good idea?"

Comment: @PLB what we can do with client requirement? They asked for this thing storing all feeds in database and then publish them to front end by choosing.

Comment: @lvil well for database i need following fieldsdemo_feeds`(
  `Published` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Author` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Link` mediumtext CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `Categories` mediumtext CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `itemid` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`)
) ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic I hope its work for you.....

```
<?php
include('magpierss/rss_fetch.inc');
define('MAGPIE_CACHE_DIR', '/var/cache');
$rss = fetch_rss(' here is url link');
$items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, 10);

$data = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
        $href = $item['link'];
        $title = $item['title'];
        $desc = $item['description'];
        echo "<p><a href='$href'>$title</a><br>";
        if($desc)
        if (strlen($desc) >= 125)
        {
                $desc = substr($desc,0,124)."...";
        }
        echo $desc;

        $data[$i]['href'] = $href;
        $data[$i]['title'] = $title;
        $data[$i]['desc'] = $desc;

        //create insert function like this InsertDbEntry($data) and set in function $data as argument;

$i++;
}
;

function InsertDbEntry($data){
    // Also you can add if condition for check this title is already exists in database or not
    foreach($data as $dbData){
        mysql_query("insert into table ('href','title','desc') values ('".$dbData['href']."','".$dbData['title']."','".$dbData['desc']."')");
    }
}
```